# Connection attempt shows "enter valid username and password"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access-2010

When I run my program with the username and password from Access, it still shows:

> enter valid username and password

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter Username and password", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation
                   )
        Else
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*)from login where Username and Password=?", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            cmd.Dispose()
            connection.Close()


            If (count > 0) Then
                MsgBox("Login Sucessful", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("please enter valid username and password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It is just a typo or do you really have two database fields named _Username?_ and _Password?_ with the ending question mark?

Comment: Other typos are _selecct_ (just one c) and the condition for Username is missing the parameter placeholder.

Comment: this is what the error says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: @SamuelOguocha, after you have solved this issue, please review how to store the password. (https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a valid syntax:

```
"select count(*) from login where Username=? and Password=?"
```

Comment: Not nearly as silly as storing passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your code?Is there a problem connecting to the database?

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*)from login where Username=@1 and Password=@2", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
```